# angular6 RxJs observables issue

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

I am trying to retrieve a list of todos from service class in the component. But it  does not work. Please find the code below:

todos.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todos } from '../models/Todos';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodosService {

  todos: Todos[];

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  }

  private todoSource = new BehaviorSubject<Todos>({ id: null, text: null, completed: null });
  selectedTodo = this.todoSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get<Todos[]>('http://localhost:8888/api/todos').subscribe((todos) => {
      this.todos = todos;
    });
  }

  getTodos(): Observable<Todos[]> {
    return of(this.todos);
  }

  addTodo(todo): Observable<Todos> {
    return this.http.post<Todos>('http://localhost:8888/api/todos', todo, this.httpOptions);
  }

  setTodo(todo: Todos) {
    this.todoSource.next(todo);
  }
}
```

todoslist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todos } from '../../models/Todos';
import { TodosService } from '../../services/todos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.component.css']
})
export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: Todos[];
  constructor(private _todosService: TodosService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._todosService.getTodos().subscribe(todos => {
      console.log('getting todos', todos);
      this.todos = todos;
    });
  }

  onSelect(todo: Todos) {
    this._todosService.setTodo(todo);
  }
}
```

The ngOnInit method of the component calls the getTodos() method of the service. But on console logging the todos appear to be undefined. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no guarantee the data has returned from the service by the time you call `getTodos()`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the ajax should be made from the `getTodos` method itself. Having call inside `constructor` would not ensure that data to be available first. This is how async works. It can be simply return as below.

```
getTodos(): Observable<Todos[]> {
   return this.http.get<Todos[]>('http://localhost:8888/api/todos');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to cache the HTTP response so that a 2nd HTTP request is not made if the getTodos() methods is called a 2nd time.

If I am wrong then @Pankaj Parkar is correct.

If I am right then you want to do this instead:

```
getTodos(): Observable<Todos[]> {
  return (this.todos) ? of(this.todos) : 
    this.http.get<Todos[]>('http://localhost:8888/api/todos')
      .pipe( tap(todos => this.todos = todos) )
}
```